# How is a relation between elements inside a set an equivalence relation?

Tags: equivalence-relations

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 9 p. 612:

[image: img]

How can they tell $R$ is an equivalence relation right off the bat?

Comment: Practice. How else?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for any function $f:A\to B$, the relation $\{(a, a') :f(a) =f(a')\}$ is always an equivalence relation.

Prove it in this generality, and find the sets $A,B$ and the function $f$ to apply this for the problem.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, they are saying $R: A\to A$ is always an equivalence relation.  From the book: `A relation on a set A is called an equivalence relation if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.`  How can they tell it is an equivalence without checking these three properties?

Comment: They have checked it. Check them yourself as well, in the above generality.